# I get these errors trying to build a web service client in Ruby

Tags: ruby, webservice-client, soap4r

I am trying to build a web service client in Ruby.

When I try to invoke the following soap4r ruby script to generate web service client code:

```
wsdl2ruby.rb --wsdl *[web_service_url]* --type client
```

I get the following error:

> ignored attr: {http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl}Action
>   I, [2011-06-09T17:16:01.012268 #10104]  INFO -- app: Creating class definition.
>   I, [2011-06-09T17:16:01.012268 #10104]  INFO -- app: Creates file 'SessionServic
>   e.rb'.
>   F, [2011-06-09T17:16:01.014268 #10104] FATAL -- app: Detected an exception. Stop
>   ping ... undefined method `collect' for #<String:0x32260c8> (NoMethodError)
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/codegen/gensupport.rb:2
>   39:in`trim_eol'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/codegen/gensupport.rb:2
>   27:in `format'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/codegen/commentdef.rb:2
>   7:in`dump_comment'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/codegen/classdef.rb:51:
>   in `dump'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/classDefCreator.r
>   b:118:in`block in dump_complextype'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/classDefCreator.r
>   b:116:in `collect'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/classDefCreator.r
>   b:116:in`dump_complextype'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/classDefCreator.r
>   b:60:in `dump'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:77:i
>   n`block in create_classdef'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:171:
>   in `block in write_file'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:170:
>   in`open'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:170:
>   in `write_file'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:76:i
>   n`create_classdef'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:62:i
>   n `create_file'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:42:i
>   n`run'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:46:in `run'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:691:in`start'
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:137:in `<top (
>   required)>'
>   C:/Ruby192/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:19:in`load'
>   C:/Ruby192/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:19:in `'
>   I, [2011-06-09T17:16:01.016268 #10104]  INFO -- app: End of app. (status: -1)

When, I try to invoke the following code to dynamically generate the web service client:

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'

WSDL_URL = "http://*[web_service_url]*"
factory = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(WSDL_URL)
driver = factory.create_rpc_driver
```

I get the following error:

> C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in `initialize': The requested service
>   provider could not be loaded or
>   initialized. - socket(2)
>   (http://*web_service_url*) (Errno::E10106)
>     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in`new'   from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in `create_socket'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:705:in`block in connect'  from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in
>   `timeout'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in`
>   timeout'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:704:in `connect'   from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:568:in`query'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:158:in `query'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1057:in`
>   do_get_block'    from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:866:in
>   `block in do_request'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:953:in`
>   protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
>     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:865:in
>   `do_request'  from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:938:in`
>   follow_redirect'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:577:in
>   `get_content'     from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/xmlSchema/importer.rb:73:in`
>   fetch'   from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/xmlSchema/importer.rb:36:in
>   `import'  from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/importer.rb:18:in`
>   import'  from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/wsdlDriver.rb:146:in
>   `import'  from
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/wsdlDriver.rb:32:in`
>   initialize'  from
>   C:/DevProjects/application-development-environment/UwsSampleRuby/blah.rb:6:in
>   `new'     from
>   C:/DevProjects/application-development-environment/UwsSampleRuby/blah.rb:6:in`
>   '

When I try to invoke the same code above, but with the a different URL (the production URL instead of the test environment URL), I get a different error:

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.  (https://[prod_url]:443) (SocketError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in`new'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in `create_socket'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:705:in`block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in`timeout'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:704:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:568:in`query'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:158:in `query'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1057:in`do_get_block'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:866:in `block in do_request'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:953:in`protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:865:in `do_request'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:938:in`follow_redirect'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httpclient-2.2.1/lib/httpclient.rb:577:in `get_content'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/xmlSchema/importer.rb:73:in`fetch'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/xmlSchema/importer.rb:36:in `import'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/importer.rb:18:in`import'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/wsdlDriver.rb:146:in `import'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/wsdlDriver.rb:32:in`initialize'
    from C:/DevProjects/application-development-environment/UwsSampleRuby/blah.rb:6:in `new'
    from C:/DevProjects/application-development-environment/UwsSampleRuby/blah.rb:6:in`'

Why am I getting these errors, and how do I work around them? I know the web services are up and working, since I'm able to build web service clients in C# .Net just fine.

Answer (score 1):

soap4r has a number of known issues with Ruby 1.9. You should consider using one of the newer SOAP toolkits, such as [savon](http://savonrb.com/) or [handsoap](https://github.com/unwire/handsoap).

Comment: I tried switching to both of these toolkits, and in either case, I get the same errors as before. It seems the issue is lower-level than that.